# OnClick not firing on functional component in Router

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-router-dom

I'm new to React JS and I have some trouble with an onClick event.
I tried multiple things but as I'm new, I'm certainly missing something.
I'm using codesandbox with react-router-dom.

Here's my code, I tried to removed un-necessary parts.

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  state = { selectedCharacters: [], minPlayer: 10, };
  selectCharacter = clickedCharacter => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      selectedCharacters: prevState.selectedCharacters.concat(clickedCharacter)
    }));
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedCharacters } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <CharactersSelection availableCharacters={this.props.availableCharacters} selectedCharacters={selectedCharacters}          selectCharacter={this.selectCharacter}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const CharactersSelection = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          {props.availableCharacters.map((char, i) => (
            <CharacterCardSelection
              imgName={char.imgName}
              name={char.name}
              maxInGame={char.maxInGame}
              onClick={() =>props.selectCharacter(char)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  );
};

const CharacterCardSelection = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img className="char-img-sm" src={require("../../public/images/" + props.imgName)}/>
      <div className="char-card-selection-txt">
        <div className="char-card-selection-name">{props.name}</div>
        <div>{props.maxInGame}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Content = props => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="content align-items-stretch">
        <div className="row">
           <div className="menu col-2">
             <div>
              <Link to="/charactersSelection" class="bm-item"style={menuLinkStyle}>
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-play-circle" />
                <span>Nouvelle Partie</span>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="contentGame col-10">
            <div>
               <Route path="/charactersSelection" component={() => (<Game {...props} availableCharacters={props.availableCharacters}/>)}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  availableCharacters = [{ imgName: "base_loup.png", name: "Loup Garou", maxInGame: 4 },{ imgName: "base_chasseur.png", name: "Chasseur", maxInGame: 1 },       { imgName: "base_voyante.png", name: "Voyante", maxInGame: 1 }];
  render() { return ( <div> <Content availableCharacters=this.availableCharacters} /> </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

When I click on the component CharacterCardSelection nothing happens, where am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get a warning that `CharacterCardSelection` is missing a key prop?  You can do `<CharacterCardSelection key={i} .../>` and see if that's the issue

Comment: you are just placing onclick event at wrong place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because, you are not attaching the `onClick` event to any node, you are just passing the function to child component, here:

```
<CharacterCardSelection
  imgName={char.imgName}
  name={char.name}
  maxInGame={char.maxInGame}

  onClick={() => props.selectCharacter(char)}       // <====== here

/>
```

All the values that we pass in props will be just the object (props) entries, we need to use those values in child component, then only it will work.

You need to specify the click event to some element in CharacterCardSelection component, like this:

```
const CharacterCardSelection = props => {
  return (

    <div onClick={props.onClick}>         // <======= notice onClick in this line

      <img className="char-img-sm" src={require("../../public/images/" + props.imgName)}/>
      <div className="char-card-selection-txt">
        <div className="char-card-selection-name">{props.name}</div>
        <div>{props.maxInGame}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Suggestion:** Better to use a different name other than `onClick` to pass the event handler function to child component.

Comment: Damn, I saw this on some tutorials, should have known. Thx for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

```
const CharactersSelection = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          {props.availableCharacters.map((char, i) => (
            <CharacterCardSelection
              imgName={char.imgName}
              name={char.name}
              maxInGame={char.maxInGame}
              char={char}
              selectCharacter={ props.selectCharacter(char)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  );
};


const CharacterCardSelection = props => {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => props.selectCharacter(props.char)}>
      <img className="char-img-sm" src={require("../../public/images/" + props.imgName)}/>
      <div className="char-card-selection-txt">
        <div className="char-card-selection-name">{props.name}</div>
        <div>{props.maxInGame}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```